# XML map Boolean vs SQL BIT

Tags: c#, sql, excel, xml, database

I am trying to solve a problem for a quiet while now, but I couldn't solve it.

I am using XML data (from excel) to uploud it to SQL server. You can see how the XML is mapped.
[XML Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b69YZ.png)

The problem is, that I have to use "Boolean" (or at least that is what I have found), however in C# code, where I am uploading the file it does not like it.

```
   string sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[" + strTab + "](" +
            "[Number][int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
            "[StartPosition] [ntext] NULL," +
            "[EndPosition] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Color] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Diameter] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[CableID] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Connection] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Bridge] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[CableType] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Description] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[WireNumber] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[TerminalLevelStart] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[TerminalLevelEnd] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Done] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Date] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Time] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[DoneBool] [bit] NULL, " +
            "[PartiallyDoneBool] [bit] NULL, " +
            "[DoneNumber] [int] NULL,)";
```

Database uses "bit" and that is what I believe the root of the problem.

Is there any way, how to convert it or make it work?

Also the int at the end will not go through. So basically it is working only to the [Time].

BTW: I have tried multiple maps (for exampple without the bool or without the int) and changed the sqlcreateTable, but only times it works is without the bit and int.

Here is whole code:

```
  string sqlDropTable = "IF OBJECT_ID('dbo." + strTab + "', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo." + strTab + ";";
        SqlCommand DropTable = new SqlCommand(sqlDropTable, con);
        DropTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = '" + _tableName + "' AND xtype = 'U')
        string sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[" + strTab + "](" +
            "[Number][int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
            "[StartPosition] [ntext] NULL," +
            "[EndPosition] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Color] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Diameter] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[CableID] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Connection] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Bridge] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[CableType] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Description] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[WireNumber] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[TerminalLevelStart] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[TerminalLevelEnd] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Done] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Date] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[Time] [ntext] NULL, " +
            "[DoneBool] [bit] NULL, " +
            "[PartiallyDoneBool] [bit] NULL, " +
            "[DoneNumber] [int] NULL,)";

        SqlCommand CreateTable = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateTable, con);
        CreateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in _ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);

            }
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = strTab;
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_ds.Tables[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                MessageBox.Show("" + ex) ;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();            
            }
```

Comment: `bool` and `bit` should convert no problem between each other. What error are you actually getting? I see a few problems with your current code: `[DoneNumber] [int] NULL,)` has an extra comma. If you are in reality using a temp table then you need to do it on the same connection, so you should pass `SqlBulkCopy` your existing `con` connection. You should dispose your connection with `using` instead, as the `finally` only covers a small part of the code. I hope you are sure you won't get SQL injection with `strTab`. Consider using proper multi-line strings `@""` to make this more readable

Comment: "The given value '' of type String from data source cannot be converted to type bit for Column 16 [DoneBool] Row 1. ---> Failed to convert parameter value from String to a Boolean." I have deleted the Extra comma (thank you for that). Will definitely think about your other suggestions, but right now I'm curious, why it won't accept the bit and the int...

Comment: Well clearly it's not a `bool` then. What is the actual value of that column? If it's `""` then it can't be converted, and isn't valid according to the XSD anyway

Comment: I forgot about the value, so I added everywhere 0 and it still reads it as string...